# Highest frequencies of EMPs in space

Tags: radiation, nuclear, electromagnetism

When a nuke detonates, an EMP at about 100 MHz followd. A pulsar on the other hand, has a comparatively low frequency, and while I know that this frequency depends on its spin and doesn't represent the true frequency of the emissions, I was just wondering about which EMP-Events in space an reach the highest frequencies. I, for example, haven't found anything about Supernovas and such. And I'm specifically curious about the frequencies, less so about the associated energy. Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking about astronomical events, this is probably not the right place. You'd likely fare better at astronomy stack exchange.

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't realise that was its own separate site. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I think it's best if you ask about the [EMP phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse) here or in Physics SE, and things like signals from pulsars (which are not at all like EMPs) *separately* in Astronomy SE. You can ask as many questions as you like, and the answers to one question can server as the basis for your next question. Why not ask what the frequency spectrum of an EMP weapon's pulse really looks like? Instead of just saying it's at about 100 MHz, let's see if there's more to learn about it!

Comment: Shockwave from a supernova